# Export Morris.js chart as PDF?

Tags: javascript, html, jspdf, html2canvas, morris.js

I am creating a line chart using Morris.js which the data are retrieved from MySQL database. I wanted to download it as PDF file that contains the entire chart.

I've tried using html2canvas and jsPDF to generate the PDF. However, the PDF generated/downloaded does not contain any data on it.

Here's my code:

```
<?php 
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "testing");
    $query = "SELECT * FROM purchase";
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    $chart_data = '';

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $chart_data .= "{ year:'".$row["year"]."', profit:".$row["profit"].", purchase:".$row["purchase"].", sale:".$row["sale"]."}, ";
    }

    $chart_data = substr($chart_data, 0, -2);
?>
```

```
<div class="row">
    <div id="chart" style="width:800px;"></div>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="800px;"></canvas>
    <button onclick="save();">Download</button>  
</div>
```

```
Morris.Line({
    element : 'chart',
    data:[<?php echo $chart_data; ?>],
    xkey:'year',
    ykeys:['profit', 'sale'],
    labels:['Profit', 'Sale'],
    hideHover:'auto',
    stacked:true
});       

function save() {
    html2canvas(document.getElementById('canvas'), {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
            var img = canvas.toDataURL();
            var doc = new jsPDF();
            doc.addImage(img, 10, 10);
            doc.save('test.pdf');
        }
    });
}
```

Any ideas or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a `canvas` element as html2canvas is creating one for you.

To make it work, I used the latest html2canvas version [1.0.0-rc.1](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/releases/tag/v1.0.0-rc.1) that uses a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) instead of a callback.

Here is the `save` function:

```
function save() {
    html2canvas(document.getElementById('chart')).then(canvas => {
        var w = document.getElementById("chart").offsetWidth;
        var h = document.getElementById("chart").offsetHeight;

        var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1);

        var doc = new jsPDF('L', 'pt', [w, h]);
        doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG', 10, 10, w, h);
        doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
    }).catch(function(e) {
        console.log(e.message);
    });
}
```

A full working version: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/87jqs3t0/)

Comment: Great! I've learned something new today. For the image generated, its only getting half of the chart is might because of the jsPDF [unit](https://micropyramid.com/blog/export-html-web-page-to-pdf-using-jspdf/) used. So, I used 'pt' (points) unit instead.

Comment: Glad I could help. You're right, the unit should be 'pt'. Thanks for the feedback.